# Negative autocorrelation in linear regressions : examples and consequences

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, example

I am wondering if there are classical (or not so classical) examples of negative autocorrelation in a regression model.

To expalin the context : I am explaining OLS limitations, heterosckedasticity and autocorrelation for the moment, and I want to showcase as many examples as possible, but I have only encountered positive autocorrelation in my practical work.

And also, is there any particular theoretical results in case of such an autocorrelation, as the errors tend to "cancel each other" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have wandered online and found some examples of negative autocorrelation :

- If you've ever seen a row of cabbages growing in a garden, you'll frequently notice an alternating pattern--big cabbage, little cabbage, big cabbage, little cabbage, etc. This happens because one cabbage might have a slight edge in growth. It extends into its neighbor's space, stealing water and nutrition for itself. Because of this slight competitive edge, the one cabbage grows even bigger at the expense of the neighboring cabbage.
- If you are looking at the amount of time a doctor spends with successive patients, if the first patient finished faster than expected, you are more likely to adopt a leisurely approach with the second patient. If the first patient takes longer than expected, you are more likely to rush with the second patient, trying to get back on schedule.
- In an assembly line process where small pieces are cut from a single large piece, if the first piece is a bit long, the next piece is likely to be a bit short and vice versa.

Stille nothing on theoretical restults, and I am still willing to have new answers.